# Is there a bug in items per page when using filters?

Tags: support, user-interface, ignored-tags

Currently if I set 15 items per page I only see three. I suspect that it is due to my ignore filters. Is this by design.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ignore filters work on the client side, not on the server side. Posts are removed in your browser, after the server has delivered a full batch of 15 items to your computer.

So, provided you have the `hide ignored tags` preference enabled, what you see is normal behaviour, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: ok, I guess it is the answer then. Still found it a a little < optimal. (+1 obviously)